# C# Change my sitemap from ashx to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

My sitemap is at: http://localhost/scirranew/sitemap.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SiteMap" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class SiteMap : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

As far as I know, google will be OK with this.  But I would like it to be a .xml filetype for consistency throughout my site.

I've tried rewriting the URL:

```
<rewrite url="^~/Sitemap.xml" to="~/SiteMap.ashx" processing="stop"/>
```

But this doesn't work with the .xml extension.

Comment: Obviously, that link will not work for us unless we are running your application :)  But I suppose it was unintentionally auto-linked.

Comment: @mell yeah it's just for illustration

Comment: Does it not work because it doesn't go through the rewrite processor?  You might need wildcard extension mapping, like http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/

Comment: @mell <rewrite url="^~/SiteMap/Sitemap.ashx" to="~/SiteMap.ashx" processing="stop"/> works fine, do I need to set up the extension xml specially or something?

Comment: your problem is probably that your webserver is not configured to let asp.net handle the .xml extension. normally and out of the box .xml is considered as a static file and is therefor served as it is without any processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `ashx` file, just put the code in an assembly and [register the handler in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx) with any extension you like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Sitemap.xml" 
        type="SiteMap, AssemblyContainingClass" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've had a look on google, I'm new to putting code in assembly, how do I do this?

Comment: @TomGullen, create a new ClassLibrary project, add the class, add reference to system.web, press compile.

Comment: this will still not help you if .xml is not configured to be handled by asp.net in the webserver