# how do you pull XML data from a C# file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

If I have XML data in a C# file, instead of using setXMLUrl(/blah.blah.xml); to retrieve the XML information from an XML file, what function or code do I need to pull XML data from a C# file that is used in ASP.net?

This is what the code is:

```
myChart.setXMLUrl("/Controls/TaskOrder/TaskSummary.asc/TaskSummary.ascx.cs");
```

I am rendering a chart so in the setXMLUrl(""); area is where the data is being read from. Usually it is from an XML file like this:

```
myChart.setXMLUrl("data/data.XML");
```

but since my XML data is appended in a C# file, I can't use setXMLUrl since it is not referencing XML directly.

Here is an updated look at the code behind:

```
    public void SetLine3Chart(DataSet exDT)
    {
        StringBuilder xmlData = new StringBuilder();

        xmlData.Append("<chart caption='Current Period: Total Months: 12' chartBottomMargin='8' chartTopMargin='04' captionPadding='01' xAxisNamePadding='-20' yAxisNamePadding='05' chartRightMargin='20' showBorder='0' yAxisName='' xAxisName='' numberPrefix='$' formatNumberScale='0'>");
        xmlData.Append("<categories>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='January'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='February'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='March'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='April'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='May'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='June'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</categories>");

        xmlData.Append("<dataset seriesName='Budget Spent' >");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='3478'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='2557'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='5379'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4987'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='1790'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='6367'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</dataset>");

        xmlData.Append("<dataset seriesName='Average Spending' renderAs='Line'>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4375'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4675'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='6354'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='7648'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4578'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4763'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</dataset>");
        xmlData.Append("<styles>");
        xmlData.Append("<definition>");
        xmlData.Append("<style name='Font_0' type='font' font='Arial' size='12' color='666666' rightMargin='15' />");
        xmlData.Append("</definition>");
        xmlData.Append("<application>");
        xmlData.Append("<apply toObject='CAPTION' styles='Font_0'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</application>");
        xmlData.Append("</styles>");
        xmlData.Append("</chart>");

        Literal9.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart("/Dashboard/Charts/MSCombi2D.swf", "", xmlData.ToString(), "line3Chart", "100%", "100%", false, false);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the XmlFileReader? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

Comment: Do you mean string variable with xml in it?

Comment: Clarify. Do you have XML embedded as a string, inside a C# file, (either a code behind file, or another cs file) and you just want to stream that XML to the Browser?

Comment: yes it is a code behind

Comment: Literal9.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart("/Dashboard/Charts/MSCombi2D.swf", "", xmlData.ToString(), "line3Chart", "100%", "100%", false, false);

Comment: Not the best decision ever that was it? You are going to have to dig the xml out of the cs file before you can do anything with it.

Comment: @Keith: The question is, where is the XML, if it's in the code behind, is there a reason? Why can't you separate it from the code behind file?

Comment: That is not xml embedded in cs file!

Comment: I'm not sure if I could or not, all of the xmlData is Appended using Literal's. Is there an easier way to do this? I'm building Fusion Charts and there needs to be data to reference the chart.

Comment: This is more about FusionCharts.

Comment: You should never use string concatenation or other string methods to create XML. Those functions don't know the rules of XML, so will break the XML. Use the XDocument/XElement or XmlDocument/XmlElement classes.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very strange:

```
myChart.setXMLUrl("/Controls/TaskOrder/TaskSummary.asc/TaskSummary.ascx.cs");
```

You are probably wrong. :-)

You must connect xml/json data from url. So, create ashx handler to provide XML/json data by some arguments and than put url of this handler to your script. Also take a look, if there would be possibility to give data to FusionChart object from javascript variable. It may help.

Here you can see ashx handler sending XML data: [C# Change my sitemap from ashx to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223520/c-sharp-change-my-sitemap-from-ashx-to-xml) (only data are missing).

Comment: So clarify if you could, here is my code     FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
    var myChart = new FusionCharts("/Dashboard/Charts/MSCombi2D.swf", "popChartDiv", "100%", "100%", "0");
    myChart.setXMLUrl("/Controls/TaskOrder/TaskSummary.ascTaskSummary.ascx.cs");
    myChart.render("test");          what does this code do and where would I put it?

Comment: yes the myChart.setXMLUrl(""); does look strange cause I need a XML file there. I just put in where the actual file is located is all.

Comment: +1 Fanda is correct. You will want to render XML/JSON from a page/ashx handler that you can consume.